# For maven dependencies from local repository, Eclipse can't open Javadoc in the browser

Tags: eclipse, browser, javahelp

When from within Eclipse I try to open Javadoc in a browser, using the button "Open attached Javadoc in a browser" in the pop-up Javadoc window, for example, for JAssert that is in the local M2E repository, the browser opens an empty page. The URL, passed to the browser, is `http://127.0.0.1:47264/help/nftopic/jar:file:/C:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/org/assertj/assertj-core/3.22.0/assertj-core-3.22.0-javadoc.jar!/org.assertj.core/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#assertThat(java.lang.String)`

The file mentioned in the URL exists and contains the required Javadoc. The Javadoc location set in the project's Java Build Path for the library looks correct, it reads `\Users\xxx\.m2\repository\org\assertj\assertj-core\3.22.0\assertj-core-3.22.0-javadoc.jar`, and Eclipse shows the Javadoc in the pop-up window.

Is the URL correct? Is it Eclipse who responds on port 47264? If the URL is correct, why can't eclipse serve the request? If it's wrong, where in Eclipse can I fix it?

UPD: Both the jar file in the abovementioned location, and the path inside the jar exist, they can be opened via an explorer

[image: the url doesn't open, the file opens:]

Comment: Yes, Eclipse responds on that port. Does _Help > Help Contents_ work or is something blocking it (maybe because of HTTP instead of HTTP**S**)?

Comment: @howlger Yes, it works, but it doesn't show the assertJ help. and it shows its content in an own Eclipse window, not in the browser

Comment: Could you please try to drag and drop (or copy) a link from the help window to your browser?

Comment: @howlger Yes. The link looks like 'http://127.0.0.1:47264/help/topic/org.eclipse.egit.doc/help/EGit/Git_For_Eclipse_Users/Git-For-Eclipse-Users.html' (for example), and the browser shows the corresponding ecliple-styled page

Comment: Okay, so nothing is blocking it (help works with the same web server). I can not reproduce your issue. Please double-check whether your Eclipse is up to date, whether the path of the JAR (case insensitive: `C:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/org/assertj/assertj-core/3.22.0/assertj-core-3.22.0-javadoc.jar`) and the path inside the JAR (case sensitive: `org.assertj.core/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html`) is correct. Please try also other links and the link without the anchor (`assertThat(java.lang.String)`).

Comment: @howlger The paths seem to be OK, I've attached a picture to the initial post. Eclipse is up to date. Neither other anchors in this jar file, nor other files in this folder open. An apparent difference between the two URLs (Eclipse help and AssertJ javadoc) is that the former contains `...14826/help/index.jsp?topic=...` while the latter contains `...14826/help/nftopic/jar:file:/C:/...`. Is the latter URL syntax correct? And now the port number has changed... Is not it a constant? Does in mean anything?

Comment: Yes, a random port number is chosen unless you define one via `-Dserver_port=...` in the `eclipse.ini` in the `-vmargs` section. According to your screenshot the URL part of the HTML file inside the JAR is wrong: it has to start with `!/org/...` instead of `!/org.assertj.core/org/...` So, something might be wrong with your project configuration.

Comment: @howlger Thank you very much! Yes, the URL without `org.assertj.core/` works fine. I'll try to figure out where and why it gets spoiled and how to fix it. If you would write the matter of the issue as an answer, i wuold be glad to upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot, the **URL** part that specifies the path of the HTML file inside the JAR is wrong: it **has to be without `/org.assertj.core`**, so that it start with `!/org/...` instead of `!/org.assertj.core/org/...` Maybe something is wrong with your project configuration.

The URL `http://127.0.0.1:47264/help/nftopic/jar:file:/C:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/org/assertj/assertj-core/3.22.0/assertj-core-3.22.0-javadoc.jar!/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#assertThat(java.lang.String)` consists of the following parts:

- `http://127.0.0.1:47264/help/nftopic/jar` - Eclipse internal web server to show files contained in a JAR in an external web browser (`47264` is a random port number unless the port number is given via `-Dserver_port=...`)
- `file:/C:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/org/assertj/assertj-core/3.22.0/assertj-core-3.22.0-javadoc.jar` - URL of the JAR file
- `!` `/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html` - path of HTML file inside the JAR
- `#` `assertThat(java.lang.String)` - anchor of the `assertThat(...)` method inside the HTML file